# How to Map value of a tag without creating a POJO?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following XML in a String form

```
<INSTANCE number="4" price="254.00">
    <DESCRIPTION value="test"/>
    <QUANTITY value="10"/>
    <TOTALPRICE value="2540.00"/>
</INSTANCE>
```

I am trying to Map it to an object using JAXB for which I have created the following POJO
This is the class which I am using to map the XML mentioned above

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "INSTANCE")
@XmlAccessorType(value = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class InstancePriceExtended {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "number")
    private String number;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "QUANTITY")
    private String quantity;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TOTALPRICE")
    private String totalPrice;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder toStringBuilder;
        toStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("InstancePriceExtended{");
        toStringBuilder.append("number=").append(this.number);
        toStringBuilder.append(",price=").append(this.price);
        toStringBuilder.append(",description=").append(this.description);
        toStringBuilder.append(",quantity=").append(this.quantity);
        toStringBuilder.append(",totalPrice=").append(this.totalPrice);
        toStringBuilder.append('}');
        return toStringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the response I finally get

```
InstancePriceExtended{number=4,price=254.00,description=null,quantity=null,totalPrice=null}
```

As is evident from the above description, quantity, total price is getting set to null.
How can I get the values set to these variables without having to create separate POJO for each variable?

NOTE: The xml structure can not be modified

EDIT1: I have also tried changing the annotaions from XmlAttribute to XmlElement for the ones which are not just attributes in the original XML

```
@XmlElement(name="DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
@XmlElement(name="QUANTITY")
private long quantity;
@XmlElement(name="TOTALPRICE")
private double totalPrice;
```

After this the result which I got looked as follows
InstancePriceExtended{number=4,price=7704.0,description=,quantity=0,totalPrice=0.0}

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the XML layout, and in the XML layout several of your fields map to elements (not attributes), you need to *not* specifically tell JAXB to look for them in attributes.  (By default it would be looking for child elements, which is what you want; though you may still need to use @XmlElement annotations to get the element names to map, since IIRC everything involved is probably case-sensitive.)

Comment: I have also tried with & without specifying @XmlElement as well. The only thing which changed was I got default values instead of null

Comment: @PeeyushPathak ; I am not able to reproduce that behavior.  I have used JAXB in exactly this way numerous times and it has never imposed defaults over the values actually in the document.  I suggest updating your question to reflect each approach you've tried, and the results of those attempts, in sufficient detail that they can be reproduced.

Comment: I tried this                                                
   @XmlElement(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;                                                                           This is what I got InstancePriceExtended{number=4,price=7704.0,description=,quantity=0,totalPrice=0.0}

Comment: @PeeyushPathak : Adding a comment is not updating your question, and one line describing what you tried is not "each approach you've tried, and the results of those attempts, in sufficient detail that they can be reproduced".  My recommendation remains; if you don't wish to follow it, I'm bowing out.  Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to be rude; I know you are just trying to help. Have updated the question now.